# How to differentiate between using ∧ and → when translating English sentences into first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm having trouble differentiating between using ∧ and → when it comes to translating English to First Order Logic. For example, the sentence

```
"every blue node is adjacent to a red node"
Answer: ∀x(B(x) → ∃y((E(x, y) ∨ E(y, x)) ∧ R(y)))
```

My interpretation for this sentence is that for every node, if the node if Blue then there exists another node y such that X is adjacent to Y and Y is Red.

But then when I inspect this following sentence, I get confused:

```
"between any two nodes, there is a path from one to the other of length at most three." 
Answer: ∀x∀y(x = y ∨ E(x, y) ∨ ∃z(E(x, z) ∧ E(z, y)) ∨ ∃z∃w(E(x, z) ∧ E(z, w) ∧ E(w, y)))
```

Why isn't the part of the answer that's

```
"∃z(E(x, z) ∧ E(z, y))", 
not "∃z(E(x, z) → E(z, y))"
```

and this part

```
"(E(x, z) ∧ E(z, w) ∧ E(w, y))",
not "((E(x, z) ∧ E(z, w)) → E(w, y))"
```

or something like this?

I can kinda understand why but when I think about translating english into FoL I get quite confused. Can anyone please explain to me how to differentiate between using  ∧ and → to translate English to First Order Logic. Maybe this example isn't the best but my confusion remains on this. I would really appreciate some help on this please.

Comment: Why would you think that $\exists z(E(x,z)\to E(z,y))$ means "there is a path of length $2$ from $x$ to $y$"?

Comment: $∃z(E(x, z) ∧ E(z, y))$ reads that there is a node $z$ (maybe somewhere we have to specify that it is different from $x$ and $y$...) such that an edge connects $x$ with $z$ and a second one connects $z$ with $y$. This formalizes the part: "a path of length 2". The same for that of length 3.

Comment: Having said that, if we write instead $∃z(E(x, z) → E(z, y))$ we have that the formula is true also for a node $z$ whatever that is not connected to $x$ (in such case $E(x,z)$ is False and a conditional with false antecedent is True) and this is not what we mean.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah okay, so I suppose that when I'm dealing with translating English to FoL, and when considering Implication, I'll have to think about whether the statement is to remain true if the antecedent is false, and whether that should be satisfiable given the context?

Comment: Yes; the rule of thumb is that we have $\forall x (Ax \to Bx)$ and $\exists x (Ax \land Bx)$.

Comment: Very very much appreciated @MauroALLEGRANZA :)